# Question about a circuit problem with opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I would like to solve the following circuit, but I can't understand why i1=0, whereas i2=v2/R1.

If i2 is not equal to 0, where does the current go after the first resistor?

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing this backwards calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the node connected to the negative terminal of the voltage source ground.

The left side of R1 is at 0 V because it's connected to ground.

The right side of R1 is at 0 V because it's connected to the virtual ground at the summing node of the op-amp.

Therefore there's no voltage across the resistor, so no current through it.

> If i2 is not equal to 0, where does the current go after the first resistor?

Into the output pin of the op-amp.

The output pin of the op-amp behaves (somewhat) like an ideal voltage source. An ideal voltage source can have whatever current is necessary through it, positive or negative, to produce the voltage it is sourcing.